# Error in read.table

Tags: r

I am unable to specify the correct argument for `row.names` in the function `read.table()`

here is simple text:

```
 name      sex     age  height  
1 x1        F       18   162  
2 x2        M       19   170  
3 x3        M       21   178  
4 x4        F       22   166  
5 x5        F       23   165
```

when i read:

```
data1=read.table('test',head=T,sep='',row.names=T)  
invalid 'row.names' specification  

data1=read.table('test',head=T,sep='',row.names=T)  
invalid 'row.names' specification
```

Other info:

```
> version  
               _                            
platform       i686-pc-linux-gnu             
arch           i686                           
os             linux-gnu                      
system         i686, linux-gnu                
status                                        
major          2                              
minor          15.1                           
year           2012                           
month          06                             
day            22                             
svn rev        59600                         
language       R                              
version.string R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)  
nickname       Roasted Marshmallows
```

Comment: It is bad style to cry "bug" without very compelling evidence. I usually assume that I did something wrong before I blame the software.

Comment: For everybody who downvoted in (perhaps justified) irritation: Rather than punishing a newby, maybe it's more constructive to edit the question to remove the inflammatory wording?

Comment: You're right. I retracted my downvote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `read.table` the argument `row.names` has to be inputted with a number (i. e. the column number that contains the row names) or a vector of names. See `?read.table` for a complete explanation. Here:

```
data1 <- read.table('test',header=T,sep=" ",row.names=1)
```